# How to get key taken from data taken from website API

Tags: java, json-simple

I am currently coding in Java using Eclipse.  I am trying to obtain the value of the key "high" given the data

{"high": "639.00000", "last": "634.94000", "timestamp": "1476220216", "bid": "634.94000", "vwap": "630.07099", "volume": "7939.75947138", "low": "613.83000", "ask": "636.50000", "open": "616.37000"}

which I get from this address :  "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/btcusd/"

So far, I got this code:

```
package JsonSimpleExample;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.json.simple.*;



public class JsonSimpleExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/btcusd/");

        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is =con.getInputStream();


        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        System.out.println(br.readLine());

    }
}
```

A possible solution is to write the data I get from the website into a file and input each key, value pair into a hashmap and call for the value but that seems very highly redundant.  Is there any way to directly obtain a value for a key with the data that the API gives me?

Comment: not sure about the api but you could read the JSON object into a single string, remove the brackets, split around a comma and then go through that array and split those strings around the colon to get your key value pairs?

Comment: this link might help you out https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Please don't just jump at it with simple string matching or a regular expression. Use a JSON parser. It comes with the JDK. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html

Comment: Is the problem here the network traffic or parsing the JSON? Your question seems to be about JSON,  but your code only shows network I/O. Please use a JSON parser and provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that shows where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Simple you need to add json library also.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.json.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author BTACTC
 */
public class JsonExample {

    URL url;
    String str;
    Scanner scan;
    JSON json;

    public JsonExample() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        url = new URL("https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/ticker/btcusd/");

        scan = new Scanner(url.openStream());

        str = new String();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            str += scan.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println(str);// checking the data is now in string

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(str);
        System.out.println(obj.getString("high"));;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JsonExample JE = new JsonExample();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  This worked except I had to make a few changes:

Comment: 1.  I threw in JSONExceptions in both the method and the main.
2.  I had to change JSON json to JSONML json

It worked perfectly after that.